# How to change Password of KeyStore File in Java?

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore, java-security

I am using java `KeyStore` to store user secure information and locking (encrypting) the key store with password and retrieving the information with password when needed, which is working fine.

But i don't know how to change the password for the same keyStore file

i am using `KeyStore.load(InputStream,Password)` method to accessing the keystore with user password and `keyStore.store(Keystore,password)` for writing the values into keyStore.

Is there any way to change the password of keyStore file.
i have checked the api documentation give here :
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html](http://Java%20Keystore%20Documentation)

Comment: Have you tried rewriting your keystore to the same file, but a different password, using the `store(OutputStream, char[])` method?

Comment: it worked for me thank you @DanailAlexiev , i have posted the code in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Danail Alexiev its works, loading the `KeyStore` with old password and the overwriting the same keyStoreStream with new password will change the keyStore password (encrypt the keystore content with new password)

here is the code for reffrence:

```
InputStream keyStoreStream = ontext.openFileInput ( filename );
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance ( KeyStore.getDefaultType ( ) );
keyStore.load ( keyStoreStream, oldPass );
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput ( filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
keystore.store ( fileOutputStream, newPassword );
fileOutputStream.close ( );
```